# PHP Razorpay namespacing conflict with application's autoloader

Tags: php, namespaces, razorpay, spl-autoload-register

I'm trying to integrate Razorpay client into my existing app and having the issue:

```
Warning: include_once(MY XAMPP PATH/system/classes/Razorpay\Api\Api.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in MY XAMPP PATH\system\JCApp.php on line 18
```

Here are the contents,

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once('system/MyApp.php');
$app = new MyApp();
$app->init();
$rzpyObj = $app->loadRazorPay();
?>
```

**MyApp.php**

```
<?php
use Razorpay\Api\Api;
class MyApp {
    
    public function init() {
        $this->maintenanceMode();
        $this->loadConfig();
        $this->loadClasses();
    }
    
    public function loadClasses() {
        spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
            include_once __DIR__. '/classes/' . $className . '.class.php';
        });
    }
    
    public function loadRazorPay() {
        require(__DIR__. '/third-party-libs/razorpay-config.php');
        require(__DIR__. '/third-party-libs/razorpay/Razorpay.php');
        return new Razorpay\Api\Api($keyId, $keySecret);
    }
```

My directory structure:

```
|-- index.php
|-- system
   |-- MyApp.php
   |-- third-party-libs
      |-- razorpay-config.php
      |-- razorpay
         |-- all files of razorpay as in github
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Error is quite clear, there is no such file. When you `require` a file, it is the same as copying it in to the original file. I would suggest using something like Composer to handle your autoload and save yourself the trouble.

Comment: Thanks. But at this point, is there an option to work this out without Composer? I know that I don't want to autoload razorpay files. I just need to include razorpay.php but that is under RazorPay\Api\Api.

Comment: Change `return new Razorpay\Api\Api($keyId, $keySecret);` to either `return new \Razorpay\Api\Api($keyId, $keySecret);` and drop the `use` for it, other `return new Api($keyId, $keySecret);`